# Div com outros divs dentro

Tags: css, div

Eu só quero fazer uma `div`, como se fosse uma janela do windows, com titulo, corpo e uma barra de botões no fim. Mas não sei porquê, dependendo do tamanho da janela, ele "vaza" ou fica sobrando tela... Eu queria que o título e a barra tivessem tamanhos fixos, e o corpo tomasse o resto da tela. Olhem meu código:

```
<div id='tela' class='tela'>
    <div id='tela_titulo' class='tela_titulo'>TITULO</div>
    <div id='tela_corpo' class='tela_corpo'>CorpoCorpo</div>
    <div id='tela_botao' class='tela_botao'>botao</div>
</div>
```

e o `css`:

```
.tela
{  
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid #ffec24;
}

.tela_titulo
{  
  position:relative;
  height:10%;
  border:2px solid #000000;
}

.tela_corpo
{  
  position:relative;
  height:80%;
  border:2px solid #000000;  
}

.tela_botao
{  
  height:10%
  border:2px solid #000000;  
}
```

Mas desse jeito ele tá jogando a barra para fora da `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade esse vazamento ocorre por causa das bordas. No modo que o `CSS` funciona, cada elemento possui a altura em porcentagem *mais* o tamanho da borda. Exemplo: a altura do `.tela_titulo` é, na verdade, `2px` + `10%` + `2px`.

Junto a isso, você deve considerar que os `10%` de altura pode não ser exatamente o que você precisa, pois, quando a `div` for muito pequena, a barra `.tela_titulo` vai ficar minúscula.

Minha abordagem para esse caso:

```css
div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tela{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tela div{
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.tela_titulo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
}

.tela_corpo{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.tela_botao{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id='tela' class='tela'>
    <div id='tela_titulo' class='tela_titulo'>TITULO</div>
    <div id='tela_corpo' class='tela_corpo'>CorpoCorpo</div>
    <div id='tela_botao' class='tela_botao'>botao</div>
</div>
```

A propriedade `box-sizing` muda a maneira como o browser calcula as dimensões do elemento. Agora, a borda fica *dentro* da altura e da largura - ou seja, evita o problema de ter `height` + `border`.

No elemento `.tela_corpo`, usei `calc()` para dizer explicitamente: a altura deve ser 100% *menos* o tamanho da barra superior e da barra  inferior (20 + 20).

Answer (score 0):

Substitua o `height` do `.tela` para 100%.

```
.tela {  
  height:100%;
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid #ffec24;
}
```

Comment: Valews bro, uma coisa tao simples kk e eu tava apanhando...valews!